# Scala Lift - Return json object for response

Tags: scala, lift

I have the following:

```
def response() = {

    if (value == 1) { 

        ("code" -> "API_001") ~ ("result" -> "OK - Room created")

    }

}

JsonResponse(

    ("response" -> response) 

)
```

But I get the following error:

```
No implicit view available for Any => net.liftweb.json.package.JValue
```

Ay help much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def response()` is of type `Any` because your `if` clause is (if `value != 1`, it needs to return `(): Unit`, so the overall type of the expression is a supertype of `JValue` and `Unit`). You need to add an `else` clause which returns an appropriate type.